# Searching elements within list

Tags: c#, .net, csv

I want to search elements within a list:

```
public static string FindOne(string vehicleRego)
{
    string vehicleDetails = 
        Fleet.vehicleList.Find(x => x.VehicleRego == vehicleRego).ToString();

    return vehicleDetails;
}
```

But I'm not having any luck - I'm not sure how to get the whole 'row' and also how to just return one of the items in the object, say 'model'.

Comment: Could you give more details about what you mean by "But I'm not having any luck"? You've got a method - so in what way does that not work at the moment? Admittedly I'd probably use LINQ and `Where`, and consider what happens if there's 0, 1 or more than one matching vehicle, but that's a side issue.

Comment: @DaisyShipton very new to C# - trying to validate whether I'm on the right path or not for what I'm trying to do.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`vehicleList` is of type `List<Vehicle>` and `Fleet.vehicleList.Find` returns first match, so the return type is `Vehicle`

You could return the found `Vehicle` - this is the whole "row". If not found, null is returned.

```
public static Vehicle FindOneByRego(string vehicleRego)
{
    return Fleet.vehicleList.Find(vehicle => vehicle.VehicleRego == vehicleRego);
}
```